# Send prefill message PrivateMsg

Tags: 7, users, privatemsg

I need a feature for my website, I want that users can send pre-filled messages to others users.

Like in an user's profile page, they just have to click on a button and then, the pre-filled message is sent.

I'm using [PrivateMsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module, I don't know if this module could do the job

(By the way I'm new to Drupal).

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You may implement this: [hook_privatemsg_message_presave_alter](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21privatemsg%21privatemsg.api.php/function/hook_privatemsg_message_presave_alter/7).

> Change the message before it is stored.

The `$message` variable contains the message's body (as well as much more parameters) ready to be edited. Note that you can include [html tags](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp) in your message. Here is a code sample:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_privatemsg_message_presave_alter().
 * Change the message before it is stored.
 */
function my_module_privatemsg_message_presave_alter(&$message) {
  // dsm($message); print out the $message contents
  $name = $message->recipients['user_1']->name; // use foreach for many recipients
  $message->body = "<i>Dear $user</i>,\n <strong>you rock!</strong>";
}
```